# Error: Floor::Floor(const string &): cannot open file

Tags: c++

hope you doing well. i have problem with my code it gives me error when i try to run the program. the error is:

Error: Floor::Floor(const string &): cannot open file

here is the function:

```
Floor::Floor(const string &f_name) {
    ifstream tmp(f_name.c_str());
    tmp.ignore(100,'\n');
    int c;
    while(!tmp.eof()) {
            c = tmp.get();
            if (c != ' ' && c != '#' &&
                    c != 'L' && c != 'D' &&
                    c != 'K' && c != 'X' &&
                    c != 'E' && c != 'S' &&
                    c != 'A' && c != '\n' &&
                    c != EOF) {
                            cout << "Bad input file" << endl;
                            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }   
    }   
    fill_floor(f_name);
```

}

AND HERE IS MY MAIN:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime> // only for seed random generator
#include "game.h"
using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    srand(time(0));
    // init game
    Game game(2);

    // let's play ;)
    do {
            game.print_floor();
    } while(game.make_turn());

    if (game.stuck()) cout << "No posible moves. You lose =(" << endl;
    else if (game.won()) cout << "Congratulation!" << endl;
    else cout << "Bye!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

i am using makefile to compile the files.

Comment: Your question fails to meet the requirements for a [mcve]. Please edit your question so that it is a [mcve].

Comment: It's not clear where the filename comes from and it's impossible for us to guess at why this program can't open that file.  How have you confirmed that the filename is correct?

Answer (score 0):

You need to post more of your code to be able to get much help, but I can give some general debugging tips. Compile your code with all warnings enable and debug information (i.e. put `CFLAGS=-g -Wall` in your makefile) and then debug your code with `gdb /path/to/binary`. If you use the command `break FLOOR::FLOOR`, followed by `run` and then you can print out the file name when it breaks, you can see what file name your program is trying to open. As a first step check that this file exists, and if applicable make sure it's not open by any other program (in some environments, only one process can have a file open at a time).